# Atomic Confinement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I have been researching ion traps and more specifically their use for containing an extremely small number of atoms, such as $100-200$ atoms.

Would it be possible to contain $100-200$ individual atoms in a chamber, such as a steel chamber, with an extremely small internal bore, such that the atoms do not pass through the gaps of the chamber wall?

I assume it depends on what element the atom is, so for this case, the atoms are all mono-atomic, additionally, the structure and composition of the chamber wall will likely affect the success, but in theory is it possible to contain hydrogen gas, at room temperature on the order of $100-200$ atoms, such that the atoms will stay in the chamber and not pass through the wall or undergo quantum tunneling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that it is in principle possible to contain a small number of atoms in a remarkably well-constructed vessel at very low temperatures (to reduce the likelihood of escape). But in general atom traps are based on the utilization of extremely well-tuned laser pulses and electromagnetic fields to hold particles in a particular region of space. This method of confinement is far more reliable and also gives researchers a better idea of the location of the particles. This is quite important, as even if you contained the particles in some container, the odds of you ever finding them to do some experiment on are rather small even if the chamber seemed extremely tiny on the human scale. Barring some additional details of the problem, I’m afraid I can’t add much more than that you are right to consider the particulars of the atomic/ionic identities and the composition of the container, as these would both be critically important in the absence of other controls.